# Passing Parameters using redirect in rails controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this controller method:

```
def slide_change
 j=params[:val]
 g=TargetPortfolio.new
 @h,@lock=g.finding_the_concerned_id(j)
 #@h , @lock both are array. 
 last=TargetPortfolio.last  # TargetPortfolio is model class
 last.update_attributes(folders: @h)
 redirect_to :action => "target_port" #with this i need to pass @lock as argument
end
```

The other method target_port of controller:

```
def target_port
 @h=TargetPortfolio.last.folders
 # @lock from the slide_change
end
```

Available routes

```
slide_change GET  /slide_change(.:format)                Portfolio#slide_change
 /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format) :controller#:action
```

I have target_port.erb which uses @h and @lock .Any guesses how i can do that.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to define the value that `g` is giving in your routes.rb file for the `target_port` action.  so let's say `g` is an ID number.

in routes.rb:

```
match '/TARGET/:id', :to => 'controller#target_port', :as => :target_port
```

so in your controller you can write:

```
def slide_change
 j=params[:val]
 g=some_function(j)
 redirect_to target_port_path(g)
end
```

## update

(more detailed)

In the `new` view file, add this line

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "lock", @lock %>
```

the hidden field tag makes a param named "lock" that gets passed when the form is submitted, which you can access by putting this the `create` action of your controller:

```
def create
  ...
  @lock = params[:lock]
  ...
end
```

Comment: ah, could you put your actual code in the question then (or a more accurate representation?)

Comment: Edited it , kindly check.

Comment: I didn't get your solution , can you be more detailed plz.

Answer (score 1):

Change your redirect to
`redirect_to :action => "target_port", :lock => @lock` and load it in the `target_port` method with `@lock = params[:lock]`

Answer (score 0):

when i do this in my controller it looks like

```
redirect_to some_path(:params1 => params1_value, :params2 => params2_value)
```

Comment: what is some_path in this?

Comment: some_path would be the route you want to go to like `new_user_path(:name => 'test')`

you should run `rake routes` to find out what path you have available